# How to print array in JavaScripts

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to print value in below Response in browser,

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [name] => Hunter Gatherer
        [address] => Greenwood Plaza, 36 Blue St, North Sydney NSW
        [lat] => -33.840282
        [lng] => 151.207474
        [type] => bar
    )

  [1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => Love.Fish
        [address] => 580 Darling Street, Rozelle, NSW
        [lat] => -33.861034
        [lng] => 151.171936
        [type] => restaurant
    )

  [2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 5
        [name] => Nomad
        [address] => 16 Foster Street, Surry Hills, NSW
        [lat] => -33.879917
        [lng] => 151.210449
        [type] => bar
    )
)
```

there I want get value in **lat** and **lng** data print in using html how can I solve this ?

I want this display in map, in possible using this like this.

Thanks,

Comment: consider my updated answer if you are using google maps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, this is a PHP array. So you can't directly inject to a JavaScript array.

I also don't know which map API you are using, so I am not able give you a an exact solution. But if you follow the below snippet, you'll get the idea.

What I've done is, encoded array to a json string in PHP, then parsed it to a JavaScript array, then itearated over it and printed results to browser.

```
<?php
$a = [  

    [       "id" => 3,
            "name" => 'Hunter Gatherer',
            "address" => 'Greenwood Plaza, 36 Blue St, North Sydney NSW',
            "lat" => -33.840282,
            "lng" => 151.207474,
            "type" => 'bar',
    ],    
    [
            "id" => 1,
            "name" => 'Love.Fish',
            "address" => '580 Darling Street, Rozelle, NSW',
            "lat" => -33.861034,
            "lng" => 151.171936,
            "type" => 'restaurant',
    ],
    [
            "id" => 5,
            "name" => 'Nomad',
            "address" => '16 Foster Street, Surry Hills, NSW',
            "lat" => -33.879917,
            "lng" => 151.210449,
            "type" => 'bar',
    ]
];

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="map-data">

</div>



<script type="text/javascript">
    var arr = JSON.parse('<?= json_encode($a) ?>');

    var container = document.getElementById("map-data");

    arr.forEach(function(e) {

        for(k in e) {
            var p = document.createElement("p");
            var t = document.createTextNode(k+":"+e[k]);
            p.appendChild(t);
            container.appendChild(p);
        }
    });


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE:**

If you are using Google Maps,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&key=YOUR_API_KEY_HERE" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="map-data" style="width:500px; height:500px">

</div>



<script type="text/javascript">
    var json_data = '[{"id":3,"name":"Hunter Gatherer","address":"Greenwood Plaza, 36 Blue St, North Sydney NSW","lat":-33.840282,"lng":151.207474,"type":"bar"},{"id":1,"name":"Love.Fish","address":"580 Darling Street, Rozelle, NSW","lat":-33.861034,"lng":151.171936,"type":"restaurant"},{"id":5,"name":"Nomad","address":"16 Foster Street, Surry Hills, NSW","lat":-33.879917,"lng":151.210449,"type":"bar"}]';

    var data = JSON.parse(json_data);

    //use above snippet, retrieve data from php. 


  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-data'), {
      zoom: 12,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.85, 151.20),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    data.forEach(function(e){

      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(e.lat, e.lng),
        map: map
      });

    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Screenshot of result[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to print in console bar :

```
console.log(Array Name);
```

Answer (score 1):

In jquery you can do it using this option:

```
arrayName.forEach(function(val) {
console.log(val.lat);
console.log(val.lng);
//if you want to print it then contatenate it. just like add it in ul as in
   //example given below:

 var printit = '<li>Latitude==>'+val.lat+'&nbsp;&nbsp;Longitude==>'+val.latng+'</li>';
   $("#printedvals").append(print);// do whatever you want to do with your html here. 
        });
```

Add a ul in html code with following code where you want to print the values in browser:

```
<ul id="printedvals"></ul>
```

Comment: @ThilinaSampath I just edited my answer. Let me know if you need more information

Answer (score 1):

Suppose `var arr` is your resultant array:

```js
var arr=[];arr[0]=[];
    arr[0]['id'] = 3;
    arr[0]['name'] = 'Hunter Gatherer';
    arr[0]['address'] = 'Greenwood Plaza, 36 Blue St, North Sydney NSW';
    arr[0]['lat'] = '-33.840282';
    arr[0]['lng'] ='151.207474';
    arr[0]['type'] ='bar';
    $.each(arr,function(index,value){
    console.log(value.lat);//lat
    console.log(value.lng);//lng send these to map function to plot on map
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```